# How to define by using C# code a space between controls?

Tags: c#, location, label, picturebox

I have a `PictureBox` and two `label`s that I make dynamically in a loop. How do I calculate from picbox1 location, the label1 and label2 locations, so that align as the following example:

picbox1 label1

label2

Seems a calcula somewhat simple, but I really not thought how do now.

Comment: You can always go no-calculation-keep-it-simple and make a LayoutTable to contain the bottom label and a LayoutTable that contains the picbox and the other label. Now just put each of those outter LayoutTables in a LayoutTable and you have yourself a solution. Just tons of LayoutTables. Did I mention LayoutTable? LayoutTable. It's actually called TableLayoutPanel or FlowLayoutPanel. Work with those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help:

```
label1.Position=new Point(picbox1.Right, picbox1.Top);
label2.Position=new Point(picbox1.Left, picbox1.Bottom);
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, though for simplicity, I omitted the labels.

It starts at point p, and stacks the controls (a text box and a picture box to the right), then loops.

```
Point p = new Point(15,35);
foreach (var field in fields)
{
   Label lbl = new Label {Text = field.Key, Location = p, AutoSize =  true};
   Point ppic = lbl.Location;
   ppic.Offset(lbl.Width + 20, 0);
   Control pic;
   pic = new PictureBox {Width = 400 - ptxt.X, Location = ppic};
   p.Offset(0, pic.Height + 3);
}
```

Comment: i have multiple images in my database, and i want to show them using loop, in dynamically created picturebox, i tried this one there but no success!